# router.navigate is not changing the auxiliary route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a Service used for routing

```
export class WetterRoutingService {

    private currentUser: User;
    private defaultAbm: Abm;
    public rerouteToDefaultOnLoad: boolean = false;
    constructor (@Inject(UserService) private userService: UserService,
    @Inject(UiDataStore) private uiDataStore: UiDataStore, private router: Router) {
        // get User Data and relevant data
}
```

i made a function in this service to route to certain routes i use often (the links change dynamically based on the user and data)

```
public routeToAbmAuxMaps(id) {
    this.router.navigate( [ '/start', DATA_CONSTANTS.some_constant, id, {outlets: { aux: ['maps']}}] );
}
```

I defined the following routes:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '**',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

  {
    path: 'start/:type/:abm',
    component: AbmBlock,
    canActivate: [UserService],
    resolve: {
      model: AbmBlockResolver
    },
  },
  // some other routes
   {
     path: 'maps',
     component: MapsDetailBlock,
     outlet: 'aux'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: AbmBlock,
    resolve: {
      data: AbmBlockResolver
    },
  }
];
```

and my router-outlets in the app.html

```
        <div class="main-container" id="main-container">
            <div  class="main-panel">
                <router-outlet (activate)="onMainActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-container" id="detail-container">
            <div  class="detail-panel">
                 <router-outlet name="aux" (activate)="onDetailActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
```

when this function is called however, the router resolves this into

```
BaseUrl/#/start/constant/id
```

what i expected was

```
BaseUrl/#/start/constant/id(aux:maps)
```

Is this a Bug i should post on GitHub or did i just do something wrong?

Angular 2.4.3
TS 2.1.5

e: formatting

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `outlets` object to this: (`aux` is not an array)

```
{outlets: { aux: 'maps'}}
```

Comment: i changed the call to
    this.router.navigate( [ '/start', DATA_CONSTANTS.abm, abmId, {outlets: { aux: 'maps'}}] );
it still does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`public routeToAbmAuxMaps(id) {
    this.router.navigate( [ '/start', {outlets: { aux: ['maps'], primary: [DATA_CONSTANTS.some_constant, id]}}] );
}`

Basically split the router to **primary** and **aux** after getting into parent route